# I add a new layer in caffe. There is a parameter in this layer which cannot be changed in test cpp file

Tags: c++, caffe

```
ExtractOneDimLayer<Dtype> layer(layer_param);
ExtractOneDimParameter *extract_one_dim_param = layer_param.mutable_extract_one_dim_param();
ExtractOneDimParameter extract_one_dim_param2 = layer_param.extract_one_dim_param();
//extract_one_dim_param->set_apart(true);;//for APART mode
extract_one_dim_param->set_apart(false);//for MERGE mode
layer.SetUp(this->blob_bottom_vec_, this->blob_top_vec_);
layer.Forward(this->blob_bottom_vec_, this->blob_top_vec_);
LOG(ERROR)<< "apart=" << extract_one_dim_param2.apart();
```

The default value of "apart" is "true", then I changed the value to be "false", but the last line still display a "1" not "0". However the value of extract_one_dim_param->apart() is "0".

Comment: You set false for extract_one_dim_param, but in the last line you check the value against extract_one_dim_param2. I don't know about caffe inner workings, but these are two different variables. Isn't it the case?

Comment: Normally, the two variables point to the same memory space, but one can be changed, another cannot. @KjMag